# Streaming H264 file using gst-rtsp-server

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, h.264, rtsp

GStreamer Extended Family,

Consider me a beginner in GStreamer. I am trying to stream a recorded H264 file using gst-rtsp-server. So I can play/pause/seek the video from VLC player.

Here is what I have done so far:

Recorded the H264 encoded video from IP camera's RTP H264 stream using following pipeline:

`gst-launch-1.0.exe -e -v rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.16.155/live.sdp ! rtph264depay ! h264parse !  mp4mux ! filesink location=record/video.h264`

Then, I am streaming the recorded video.h264 using following pipeline:

`gst-launch-1.0.exe -v filesrc location=record/video.h264 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000`

I am able to view the recorded video in VLC player by setting up a SDP file as shown below.

`v=0
m=video 5000 RTP/AVP 96
c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000`

But, I am not able to pause or seek the video. The above pipeline keeps playing the video even though the VLC player is not connected to port 5000.

Btw.. I tried using gst-rtsp-server's test-mp4 example to stream video.h264 but the VLC player times out the connection. The test-mp4 console output only shows single message i.e. "stream ready at rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test.

Can someone point me into a right direction to stream a recorded video using GStreamer and play/pause/seek control from VLC player over RTSP ?

Thanks,
Arm

Answer (score 0):

For the `test-mp4`:
- Remember that you must use a mp4 video with it.
- IIRC, the mp4 fle must **contains both video and audio** (because the pipeline in `test-mp4` will play both).
- After run test-mp4, check IP of the server (machine running test-mp4). In this case you stream loopback to same PC, so you can use loopback IP 127.0.0.1
- Then, on client side, open VLC and select Open Network Stream, and input the rtsp URL as : rtsp://`<Server IP>`:8554/test
For example, if server IP is 192.168.1.1, then URL is `rtsp://192.168.1.1:8554/test`

For rtsp-server:
- Just follow the example in test-mp4
- But keep in mind some points:
   + You must write an application to use rtsp-server, cannot use with gst-launch
   + All pay elements (rtph264pay in this case) must be set `name=pay*` with * is a number (pay0, pay1, pay2...)

Comment: Matilda, The IP camera I am working with encodes the video using H264encoder. So I have the H264 file, which contains both audio and video. what to change in test-mp4 example code to the H264 video/audio file ?

Comment: Your IP camera may encode both video and audio, but your 1st command to record file is video only. Thus the output video file does not contains audio. You can check by running test-mp4 with a normal mp4 video to compare, it should work fine.

Comment: Works after streaming video only in test-mp4 sample . Thanks Matilda.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I was able to stream the recorded H264 video file over RTSP/RTP if you are facing the same problem.

Modify the rtsp pipeline launch string of test-mp4 sample as shown below:

`"filesrc location=\"%s\" ! qtdemux "
      "! h264parse ! rtph264pay pt=96 name=pay0 "
       ")"`

Comment: what should i do if the source is just a raw h264 file?  i tried to use simple command `test-launch  "( filesrc location=h264.raw ! h264parse ! rtph264pay pt=96 name=pay0  )"`, unluckily, vlc responds me with `vdpau_avcodec generic error: decoder profile not supported: 7`